# Nodejs + mySQL data does not get sent to my database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to create a register and login page where the registered user's details are setn to the database and then from there they are used to verify login.

The sign up button is supposed to send data to the database, hence registering a user. After that, in the login form the data os authenticated and the user logs in.
I haven't gotten to the login part, still stuck on the sign up part.
I don't get any errors displayed, it is just that my data is not being fed to the database.

index.js for nodejs:

```
//var { app } = require("cli");
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "root",
  host: "localhost",
  password: "",
  database: "crm database",
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const CompanyCode = req.body.CompanyCode;
  const UserID = req.body.UserID;
  const UserFullName = req.body.UserFullName;
  const UserDetail = req.body.UserDetail;
  const LoginID = req.body.LoginID;
  const Password = req.body.Password;
  const ConfirmPassword = req.body.ConfirmPassword;
  const UserPin = req.body.UserPin;
  const UserEmailID = req.body.UserEmailID;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO usermst (CmpnyCode,UserID,UserFullName,UserDetail,LoginID,Password,UserPin,UserEmailID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [
      CompanyCode,
      UserID,
      UserFullName,
      UserDetail,
      LoginID,
      Password,
      UserPin,
      UserEmailID,
    ],
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 8000");
});
```

app.js for react js:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [CompanyCodeReg, setCompanyCodeReg] = useState("");
  const [UserIDReg, setUserIDReg] = useState("");
  const [UserFullNameReg, setUserFullNameReg] = useState("");
  const [UserDetailReg, setUserDetailReg] = useState("");
  const [LoginIDReg, setLoginIDReg] = useState("");
  const [PasswordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState("");
  const [ConfirmPasswordReg, setConfirmPasswordReg] = useState("");
  const [UserPinReg, setUserPinReg] = useState("");
  const [UserEmailIDReg, setUserEmailIDReg] = useState("");

  const register = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost8000/register", {
        CompanyCode: CompanyCodeReg,
        UserID: UserIDReg,
        UserFullName: UserFullNameReg,
        UserDetail: UserDetailReg,
        LoginID: LoginIDReg,
        Password: PasswordReg,
        ConfirmPassword: ConfirmPasswordReg,
        UserPin: UserPinReg,
        UserEmailID: UserEmailIDReg,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light fixed-top">
        <div className="container">Home</div>
      </nav>
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <form>
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Company Code</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="CompanyCode"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setCompanyCodeReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>User ID</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="UserID"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserIDReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>User Full Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="UserFullName"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserFullNameReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>User Detail</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="UserDetail"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserDetailReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Login ID</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="LoginID"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setLoginIDReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setPasswordReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Confirm Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder=" ConfirmPassword"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setConfirmPasswordReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>User Pin</label>
              <input
                type="Text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="UserPin"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserPinReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>UserEmailID</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="UserEmailID"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserEmailIDReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={register}>
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <form>
            <h3>Log In</h3>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Login ID</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="First Name"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you are using the url in your example, it might be wrong. I see that you are using localhos8000 and it should be localhost:8000

Comment: Thank you for that note
But it still does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I was violating my own database foreign key constraints.
I added the following line:

````
db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("Connected to MySQL Server!");
});```

after creating the database connection and it displayed to me what was going wrong.
````

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the response back to the client, you can do so with the `res` object like

`res.json({ result });`

```js
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const CompanyCode = req.body.CompanyCode;
  const UserID = req.body.UserID;
  const UserFullName = req.body.UserFullName;
  const UserDetail = req.body.UserDetail;
  const LoginID = req.body.LoginID;
  const Password = req.body.Password;
  const ConfirmPassword = req.body.ConfirmPassword;
  const UserPin = req.body.UserPin;
  const UserEmailID = req.body.UserEmailID;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO usermst (CmpnyCode,UserID,UserFullName,UserDetail,LoginID,Password,UserPin,UserEmailID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [
      CompanyCode,
      UserID,
      UserFullName,
      UserDetail,
      LoginID,
      Password,
      UserPin,
      UserEmailID,
    ],
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err);
      // You have missed this line
      res.json({ result });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: It did not work. 
Still doesn't update my databse. 
Maybe it is because my page keeps refreshing after I hit the signup button. Can you help me with that?

Comment: add this in your form tag `onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}`. I am typing from mobile, double check the syntax